# How to set the output directory for bundler logs?

Tags: ruby, git, bundler

When I run `bundle install` it generates a log file in `./.bundle/install.log`, which is alright. As the project is using `git`, I have to ignore this folder additionally.

I already have a folder `./tmp/log/`, where I would like to see this `install.log` file of the bundler, because there are other log files and they are already ignored by git.

Is it somehow possible to change the output directory for log files of the bundler for this project (not via command line arguments, so that other user of the git repository automatically also have their `install.log` in the `tmp` directory)? Maybe it's somehow controllable via the `Gemfile`?

Comment: This `install.log` was accidentally included in the 1.5.0 and 1.5.1 releases, but has been removed in 1.5.2, released today. See https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2806

Comment: True, no `install.log` any more. Thank you. Maybe you want to write a real answer, which I can accept then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the environment variable [`BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG`](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler.rb#L194-L198) to use a directory other than `.bundle`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do I need to make my own rake task, so that everyone automatically uses the environment variable? Or is there a settings file for the bundler, where I can set the variable for everyone how runs the bundler?

Comment: While there is a global settings file (which you can manipulate with `bundle config --global`), the `app_config_path` can't be set from there. Using a `rake` task might be tough because you usually want to run `rake` with `bundle exec`... a shell script wrapper, maybe?